# Flutter: How to do a smooth gradient on border?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

I am trying to do a gradient like this in my container but I don't know how to do it.

I tried to do like this:

```
 Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              gradient:
                  LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment(0.00001, 0.00001),
                    colors: [Colors.white70, Colors.black])),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, left: 3, right: 3),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30))
```

but rendering is far away from the picture. Do you have an Idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something you're looking for? You can adjust the `radius` and `focalRadius` to match your liking.

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: App()));

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 200.0,
          width: 200.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
            color: Colors.black,
            gradient: RadialGradient(
              colors: [
                Colors.black,
                Colors.white,
              ],
              radius: 2.5,
              focalRadius: 0.8,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```